# Creating a zoom function in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a function where that when a button is pressed (Several buttons the represent several animal types), that animal types SVG is updated with its corresponding data. I'm trying to replicate [this](https://bl.ocks.org/rutgerhofste/5bd5b06f7817f0ff3ba1daa64dee629d) `zoom` function but am having issues implementing it with my code. There are several SVGs that are used globally like this (one for each animal type):

```
let x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

svgReptile.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

const yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 220])
  .range([ height, 0])

svgReptile.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis))
```

The function below is called when one of the animal buttons is pressed.

```
 function update(animal, whatSVG, xAxis, yAxis, color) {   

      const points = whatSVG
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

      points.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return xAxis(d.state);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return yAxis(d.percentage);
        })
        .merge(points)
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return xAxis(d.decade)
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return yAxis(d.count)
        })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return colour(d.animal) } );

      points.exit()
        .attr('r', 0)
        .remove();

    }
```

Question:

How can I implement a zoom feature that expands the x-axis when zoomed (or anything similar) like the one linked above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a 'brush zoom' from the last line of your question.

The following source code if from an example in a [d3 graph gallery](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html)

The cross hair allows you to select an area to expand. If you follow the link there is a graph above it that is entitled "Zoom with axis" but it doesn't zoom in the way you've described, it just moves the axis, but doesn't enlarge the graph contents with it. Perhaps both will be useful!

Hope this helps

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var Svg = d3.select("#brushZoom")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([4, 8])
    .range([ 0, width ]);
  var xAxis = Svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 9])
    .range([ height, 0]);
  Svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
  var clip = Svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

  // Color scale: give me a specie name, I return a color
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["setosa", "versicolor", "virginica" ])
    .range([ "#440154ff", "#21908dff", "#fde725ff"])

  // Add brushing
  var brush = d3.brushX()                 // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
      .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] ) // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
      .on("end", updateChart) // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function

  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  var scatter = Svg.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  // Add circles
  scatter
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Sepal_Length); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Petal_Length); } )
      .attr("r", 8)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.Species) } )
      .style("opacity", 0.5)

  // Add the brushing
  scatter
    .append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush);

  // A function that set idleTimeOut to null
  var idleTimeout
  function idled() { idleTimeout = null; }

  // A function that update the chart for given boundaries
  function updateChart() {

    extent = d3.event.selection

    // If no selection, back to initial coordinate. Otherwise, update X axis domain
    if(!extent){
      if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350); // This allows to wait a little bit
      x.domain([ 4,8])
    }else{
      x.domain([ x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1]) ])
      scatter.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null) // This remove the grey brush area as soon as the selection has been done
    }

    // Update axis and circle position
    xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    scatter
      .selectAll("circle")
      .transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Sepal_Length); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Petal_Length); } )

    }



})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>



<div id="brushZoom"></div>
```

Comment: Also may be of interest: [d3 zooming api](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_zooming_api.htm)

Comment: Yes, I have read this, thank you. Whilst it's helpful, I've struggled implenting this with the global svgs and the function that updates the svgs when buttons are clicked

Comment: @JimmyNeedles what's the real issue then? Changing the source? (that wasn't included in your question)

Comment: Basically making a zoom function (like the one you linked) within the function I made above. I've tried implementing the exact one you have linked, chaning variable names where necessary, but the issues I have stem from the having several svgs globally

Comment: @JimmyNeedles have you created a zoom graph sucessfully using d3 and only one source (without trying multiple sources)?

Comment: Kind of. I have used this simple code:       `points
       .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
          points.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
       }))` after `.exit()` in the function. No errors. But no zoom effect either

Comment: Here is a demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tetasmetas/bzq5h98a/#&togetherjs=nG474Gb4Ut

Comment: target is not defined

Comment: @JimmyNeedles http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5 have a look at this example of changing datasets.